# Is there a way to run the Microsoft browser VMs on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

I do a lot of web development on Linux and Mac, and I'm also a fan of VirtualBox.

Microsoft has available for download various browser images for testing, but they require VirtualPC to run:

> [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575)

Is there a way to get these images running on VirtualBox through some conversion process, or making an image of the virtual disk or something?  What would be the process involved? I run VirtualBox 4.1 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave this a shot and it turns out no conversion is necessary.

VirtualPC will boot off the `.VHD` files just fine.  I only tried the `Windows XP IE6` image since that was the smallest to download, but I would assume the others are the same.